# Unable to remove view from linear layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I am loading a linear layout of views that represent levels in a fragment. It works fine the first time, but each time I try to adjust the views, I get an error stating illegal argument error. I call remove all views from the linear layout, so I am not quite sure what is going on.

I first did a proof of concept in just an activity and it worked fine. I should mention here that the fragment does loose focus at times, and reloads. This seems to happen only when it reloads the fragment.

Here is the code to load the views:

```
private void setMinutes(int width, int height) {

    mLevelLayout.removeAllViews();

    for(int i = 0; i < mLevelViewByMinutes.length; i++) {
         View mLevelView = mLevelViewByMinutes[i];

        if(mLevelView == null)
            mLevelView = getLevelView(width, height);   
        else
            mLevelView = adjustLevelView(height, mLevelView, i < mCurrentMinute - 1);

        mLevelLayout.addView(mLevelViewByMinutes[i] = mLevelView, i);
    }
}

private View getLevelView(int width, int height) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View levelView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_workout_level, null);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height);
    levelView.setLayoutParams(params);

    return levelView;
}

 private View adjustLevelView(int height, View levelView, boolean isNowOrPast) {
     if(isNowOrPast)
        levelView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.workout_level_white));
    else 
        levelView.getLayoutParams().height = height;

    return levelView;
}
```

And here is my error message:

```
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352): Process: ............PID: 12352
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child     already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at    android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3759)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3612)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3557)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at  com.octane.smartlink.fragments.SupplementLevelFragment.setMinutes(SupplementLevelFragment.java:97)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at com.octane.smartlink.fragments.SupplementLevelFragment.onResume(SupplementLevelFragment.java:50)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1743)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:767)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1496)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:486)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-18 09:56:03.330: E/AndroidRuntime(12352):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe your LinearLayout is reloaded/new created and when you say `.removeAllViews()` it is not the one which is holding your Views... Try to debug a little more with Logs and have a look at it. Just make `Log.e("TAG", "LinearLayout" + mLevelLayout);` and look if they are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use this workaround:

```
 if (view != null) {
    //Get the real LinearLayout which is holding your View
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    //check if it is null
    if (parent != null) {
        //remove your view
        parent.removeView(view);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I was thinking something like this. Let me check it out and see if it works.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I altered what you said to check for the parent on the first view then removing all the children of that parent. Thus, I only do this once instead of n times each time the linear layout gets modified.